# How to create linux user with only and only READ permission not EXECUTE and WRITE permission?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, shell-script

I have created user, e.g. `ronly`, now I want to give them read only access to few directories on other user home like `abc/,xyz/,pqr/` so I put this `ronly` user in others means not created any group for this user that means `ronly` will be others for above directories.Now everything work as per expectation but the only issue is that `abc/,xyz,pqr/` have some shell scripts that `ronly` should read but NOT execute them.

The shell scripts having permission like this `-rwxrw-r-- test.sh` means user `ronly` can see the scripts but should not execute them, this work for only one way like executing shell scripts like `./test.sh` this gives `permission denied` but with `sh test.sh` and `/bin/sh test.sh` can allow `ronly` to execute the scripts.

So is there any way by which I restrict them to execute shell scripts files?

Please do not suggest ACL or SElinux. I do not want to enable this due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place validation at the beginning of script.

```
userid=`id -u -n`
#echo "$userid" ;

ownuser=`ls -l ${abosolutepath}/${your_script.sh} | awk '{print $3}'`
#echo "$ownuser" ;

if [ ! "$userid" = "$ownuser" ]; then
        echo permission denied
        exit 1
fi
```

Above validation will check if the user who executing this script is same as user who own this script. If user does not match, execution will be terminated.

I have implement this in my environment and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Without involving *ACL* or *SELinux* the only way I find is adding at the beginning of the script this:

```
if [ "$USER" = "ronly" ]; then
  echo 'Access denied'
  exit 1
fi
```

This is far from perfect because:

1. The user `ronly` can read the script, so he can copy the contents to a script in his own *home* and execute it.
2. Any user can freely set their $USER environment variable, e.g. set the USER variable to `abc` and execute the script, which will bypass the restriction.

If you are doing this only to avoid *"accidental"* executions then it works, but if your aim is to REALLY forbid the execution then it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is not possible. Any user who is able to execute a shell is also able to execute any shell script they can read. The shell does not really distinguish between commands that come from the terminal and commands that come from a file.

So you would probably need some kind of restricted "shell". In principle, any program can be used as a login shell.